# do-release-upgrade does nothing after I answered a question

Tags: upgrade

Hi I have a laptop with the Ubuntu 13.04 raring/ringtail and I'm trying to upgrade it to Ubuntu 13.10 saucy/salamander.

So I entered to tty1 with `ctrl+alt+f1` and typed `sudo do-release-upgrade` and everything went fine: downloaded packages, configured them, asked about overwriting some config files and so on.

But now It asks me if I want to remove obsolete packages and of course (I don't want them to waste space) I confirmed, but nothing is happening, if I hit enter a few times more the same question reapears `Continua [sN]  Detalls [d]` (That's Catalan).

I tried everything: s, S, y, Y, n, N, si, yes, etc. The only thing that works is d to show pakages but this isn't helping me.

If I go back to the tty7 to see the processes on the `gnome-system-monitor` I have following:

login -> bash -> sudo -> saucy
with 0 CPU load on them

what can I do? should I kill the proces with ctrl+c? or should I reboot? or try different letters on the question?

Comment: If it was mine I would just cancel it ant after that try to fix it, but its my girlfriends laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I really don't know what happened, I just hit s and enter some more times and it worked!

Now I'm rebooting, and everything seems to be OK!

Comment: if your problem is solved please mark it as solved !

Comment: I'll do, but I'm getting "You can accept your own answer tomorrow" don't know why.